# Validiation check in Laravel php

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm trying to write a validation check in PHP Laravel for a username field with the functionality to let the user know what went wrong. I have a couple of if statements with regular expression checks but it won't work. The requirements of the regular expression are: can't start with a ".", No more than 1 "." in a row, No capitals, Only a-z, No special characters. So for example like this "user.name" would be valid, but things like "username." or ".username" would all be invalid.
So far I got this:

```
 $oValidator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
            'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        ]);
```

I want to give feedback for the mistakes that user makes, example: user input is ".username", program feedback should be "Dot in front of string is not allowed".

Comment: I need to let the user know where and what went wrong. Also I can use this line

            if (!preg_match("/^[a-z]+[.]?[a-z]+$/", $name)) { echo "some msg"}

 but then again the user won't know what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have tried this and this is working fine:                 'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/', 
but I want to show the users what went wrong if they made a mistake, like if they insert ".username" that the program shows a notification to the user that beginning of a string with "." is not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to include a custom message for your validation.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/',
    ], ['regex' => 'Username cannot start with period(.), etc...]);
```

Your code should look like this. Please remember regex custom message will apply too all of these fields instead of just username so I would separate username validation like above.

```
$oValidator = Validator::make(Input::all(), [
        'username' => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9][\w\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$/',
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ], ['regex' => 'Username cannot start with period, etc...']);
```

Comment: Desperation made me do this:
            if (!preg_match('/^[a-z][\w\.]+[a-z]$/', $name)) {
                $nameErr = "Invalid username, username can not start with a              dot \".\", username can not contain capitals and no special characters.";
                
            }

But your answer is worked perfectly.